# Meteor.call failing within stub?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Still new to async javascript coding, I'm trying to wrap my head around this gist: https://gist.github.com/dariocravero/3922137

Within client_save.file.js - I don't understand all parts of this stub:

```
fileReader.onload = function(file) {
    Meteor.call('saveFile', file.srcElement.result, name, path, encoding);
}
```

First of all, the argument in function(file) isn't defined - where is "file"?! Or is there some magic with "closure" that is return a value to the file argument?

Secondly, the Meteor.call doesn't trigger, I've placed console.logs within the Meteor.methods version of saveFile, and get nada. Is it because fileReader.onload = function( ... isn't a stub?

Lastly, what is fileReader.onload? Does it say when the DOM loads whatever fileReader is trying to, then invoke this function? Is there a better way to do this in meteor, using something like Meteor.template.rendered = function() .. ?

Anyways, I'm now officially twisted, can't tell top from bottom looking at this for a couple hours. Officially, I can't get the Meteor.call to trigger, following that gist.

(Using meteor 0.6.31).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use more code. fileReader is the HTML5 api that can read files you put up in an `<input type="file"` or drag and drop into the window. So when a file is loaded into the browser the `fileReader.onload` is called with `file` as the file which was loaded into the browser.

It looks like the gist is similar to [Meteor-File](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/meteor-file) a package on the atmosphere repository. But not all the code is present in that gist. Luckily Chris Mather who built it made videocasts explaining in depth how it's made : http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-file-upload-package